# Convert C# function to Delphi function

Tags: delphi

I need to convert this C# function to Delphi. I am converting a function that will generate a string based on the CPU id, BIOS id, and motherboard id.

Can anyone help me, please?

```cs
private string GetHash(string s)
{
    return ComputerInfo.GetHexString(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(s)));
}

private string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
{
    string str1 = string.Empty;
    int myLenght = bt.Length - 8;
    for (int index = 0; index < myLenght; ++index)
    {
        int num1 = (int)bt[index];
        int num2 = num1 & 15;
        int num3 = num1 >> 4 & 15;
        string str2 = num3 <= 9 ? str1 + num3.ToString() : str1 + ((char)(num3 - 10 + 65)).ToString();
        str1 = num2 <= 9 ? str2 + num2.ToString() : str2 + ((char)(num2 - 10 + 65)).ToString();
        if (index + 1 != myLenght && (index + 1) % 2 == 0)
            str1 += "-";
    }

    return str1;
}
```

---

I tried several ways to convert the functions, but I still couldn't get the same values that I get in the original function. On my laptop, I get the String `'1CB9-0485-D2FD-846C'` but in Delphi, I get the string `'3237-3939-3232-4433-4141-3835-4342-4536-4145-3344-3933-383736'`.

```pascal
function TAppForm.GetHexString(bt : TBytes) : string;
var
  str1: string;
  str2: string;
  myLength: Integer;
  index: Integer;
  num1: Integer;
  num2: Integer;
  num3: Integer;
begin
  str1 := string.Empty;
  myLength := Length(bt) - 8;
  for index := 0 to myLength do
  begin
    num1 := Integer(bt[index]);
    num2 := num1 and 15;
    num3 := num1  shr  4 and 15;
    If num3 <= 9 then
      str2 := str1 + num3.ToString()
    else
      str2 := str1 + Chr(num3 - 10 + 65);
    If num2 <= 9 then
      str1 := str2 + num2.ToString()
    else
      str1 := str2 + Chr(num2 - 10 + 65);

    if ((index + 1) <> myLength) and ((index + 1) mod 2 = 0) then
      str1  := str1 + '-';
  end;
  Result := str1;
end;

function TAppForm.MyGetMD5(Value : String) : String;
var
  workHash : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  workHash := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    Result := workHash.HashStringAsHex(Value);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(workHash);
  end;
end;

function TAppForm.GetHash(s : string) : string;
var
  //bytes: TBytes;
  bytes: TBytes;
  smd5: string;
begin
  smd5 := MyGetMD5(s);
  bytes := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(smd5);
  smd5 := GetHexString(bytes);
  Result := smd5;
end;
```

---

Thank you very much for your solution @olivier. In fact, it is very close to what I want.

However, the result I get in C# is `"1CB9-0485-D2FD-846C"` and with your solution I get `"0126-28BE-D776-1788"`.
I have tried to understand why, since the string that is requested hash is the same.

In C#, the request is as follows

```cs
GetHash("CPU >>" + ComputerInfo.CpuId() + "\nBIOS >>" + ComputerInfo.BiosId() + "\nBASE >>" + ComputerInfo.BaseId());
```

Result

```
CPU BFEBFBFF000306D4
BIOS INSYDE Corp.5.308F014604C20160325000000.000000 + 000TOSQCI - 1
BASE FF50Base BoardQC0C0Q8F3000710
```

In Delphi, the request is as follow

```pascal
const
  sLineBreak = {$IFDEF LINUX} AnsiChar (#10) {$ENDIF}
               {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} AnsiString (#13#10) {$ENDIF};

GetHash('CPU >>' + CpuId() + sLineBreak + 'BIOS >>' + BiosId() + sLineBreak + 'BASE >>' + BaseId());
```

Result

```
CPU BFEBFBFF000306D4
BIOS INSYDE Corp.5.308F014604C20160325000000.000000 + 000TOSQCI - 1
BASE FF50Base BoardQC0C0Q8F3000710
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Delphi logic does not match the C# logic.

The C# code is doing the following:

- converting a Unicode string to an ASCII byte array
- then MD5-hashing those bytes
- then encoding the bytes of that hash to a formatted hex string

The Delphi code is doing the following:

- (implicitly) converting a Unicode string to an ASCII byte array
- then MD5-hashing those bytes
- then encoding the bytes of that hash to a plain hex string
- then converting that hex string to an ASCII byte array
- then encoding those bytes to a formatted hex string

So, of course you end up with different results, because the final hex string is  being encoded from completely different inputs.

The *correct* translation should look more like this instead:

```pascal
function TAppForm.GetHash(const s: string): string;
var
  workHash : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  workHash := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    Result := GetHexString(workHash.HashString(s, IndyTextEncoding_ASCII));
  finally
    workHash.Free;
  end;
end;

function TAppForm.GetHexString(bt: TIdBytes): string;
var
  str1, str2: string;
  myLenght,
  index,
  num1, num2, num3: Integer;
begin
  str1 := '';
  myLenght := Length(bt) - 8;
  for index := 0 to myLenght-1 do
  begin
    num1 := Integer(bt[index]);
    num2 := num1 and 15;
    num3 := (num1 shr 4) and 15;
    if num3 <= 9 then
      str2 := str1 + IntToStr(num3)
    else
      str2 := str1 + Char(num3 - 10 + 65);
    if num2 <= 9 then
      str1 := str2 + IntToStr(num2)
    else
      str1 := str2 + Char(num2 - 10 + 65);
    if ((index + 1) <> myLenght) and ((index + 1) mod 2 = 0) then
      str1 := str1 + '-';
  end;
  Result := str1;
end;
```

Also, the `'\n'` char in C# is just a line  feed. It is not the same as the `#13#10` (carriage return + line feed) char sequence in Delphi on Windows. So, your input to `GetHash()` is not the same between C# and Delphi, either. You should not be using the `sLineBreak` constant at all, use just `#10` by itself, eg:

```pascal
GetHash('CPU >>' + CpuId() + #10'BIOS >>' + BiosId() + #10'BASE >>' + BaseId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working implementation. It uses [`THashMD5`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Hash.THashMD5), which is available in recent versions of Delphi.

```
uses
  System.Hash;

function GetHexString(const b: TBytes): string;
var
  len: Integer;
  index: Integer;
  num1: Byte;
  num2: Byte;
  num3: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  len := Length(b) - 8;
  for index := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    num1 := b[index];
    num2 := num1 and 15;
    num3 := (num1 shr 4) and 15;
    If num3 <= 9 then
      Result := Result + num3.ToString()
    else
      Result := Result + Chr(num3 - 10 + 65);
    If num2 <= 9 then
      Result := Result + num2.ToString()
    else
      Result := Result + Chr(num2 - 10 + 65);
    if ((index + 1) <> len) and ((index + 1) mod 2 = 0) then
      Result := Result + '-';
  end;
end;

function GetHash(const s: string): string;
var
    b, hash: TBytes;
    md5: THashMD5;
begin
    b := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

    md5 := THashMD5.Create;
    md5.update(b);
    hash := md5.HashAsBytes;

    Result := GetHexString(hash);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GetHash('Test'));
end;
```

Both C# and Delphi implementations output `0CBC-6611-F554-0BD0` for input string `Test`.